# creatition of XPCOM components

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, xpcom

I'm creating an XPCOM component using [a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87465/A-Simple-XPCOM-Tutorial) as a reference. However, when I run the following command it completes successfully but doesn't produce any `.h` file:

```
xpidl -m header -I [XUL_RUNNER SDK\IDL] myfile.idl
```

Why is that? Is XPCOM outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, XPCOM is not outdated but this tutorial is. The documentation recommends using [pyxpidl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPIDL/pyxpidl):

```
header.py -I [XUL_RUNNER SDK\IDL] -o myfile.h myfile.idl
```

Comment: i included this lines in the .bat file and run it. open with pop up window appeared and i think its because of absence of python interpreter in my set up.

Comment: i installed python latest SDK and used
python.exe [sdk\bin\header.py] -I [XUL_RUNNERSDK\IDL] -o myfile.h myfile.idl
and
python.exe sdkdir/sdk/bin/header.py --cachedir=<temppath> -o <outputfilename.h> <filename.idl>
in my batch file it was running but i'm not getting any .h files !! :'( in both cases.

Comment: Can we write XPCOM component for the latest  firefox browser's extension (14.0.0. and above)? does the browser supports it ?

Comment: It does. It's not recommended because you would need to rebuild your XPCOM component for each Firefox release (js-ctypes is the recommended solution) but you can do it.

Comment: Thanks a Lot @wladimar . it worked for me with Js-ctypes :-) is older browser(low version) support js-ctypes ?

Comment: @RaveendraPaiU: js-ctypes is supported starting with Firefox 4, that should be enough - Firefox 3.6 is outdated and no longer supported.

Comment: Thats fentastic news for me ! i need my extension to support firefox 5 and above :) Thanks a lot @Wladimir

Comment: As above mentioned . i ve created the firefox extension using js-ctype .i'm calling native normal DLL functions(written in C ) from extension.In my DLL i'm trying to load another DLL( wriiten in c++).

The problem is if i install this extension in firefox. firefox is crashing on launch..
I dont know wats the cause. Help me to debug this problem...

Comment: @RaveendraPaiU: If you have a new question - create a new question and provide the necessary information. This has nothing to do with the question you asked here.