# Using xpidl command to create .h

Tags: mozilla, xpcom

I have built Firefox from the source code, and I am trying to create a component. I try running xpidl on my `.idl` file from terminal

```
$ xpidl -m header -w -v- I $XPIDL_INC \ > -o nsIPageSummary nsIPageSummary.idl
```

but I get `-bash: xpidl: command not found`

I've tried changing the path `PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/mozilla/xpcom/typelib/xpidl`, but to no avail. I am probably just completely misunderstanding how to use the xpidl command. But is all you need the Fire fox source code it having been built? And is there a certain directory that you need to be in to use the command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creatition of XPCOM components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857907/creatition-of-xpcom-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Firefox do you use?

> Starting in Gecko 9.0 (Firefox 9.0 / Thunderbird 9.0 / SeaMonkey 2.6), xpidl has been replaced with pyxpidl in the Gecko SDK. pyxpidl has been used for some time now, but now this older tool has been fully retired.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPIDL/xpidl

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPIDL/pyxpidl

Comment: thank you! the tutorial i was reading was outdated. that solved the problem.